# Running Berkley Boot Loader on gem5 RISCV FS mode

Tags: riscv, gem5

I was trying to run Berkley Boot Loader on gem5 RISCV FS mode. I used the fs.py script provided with gem5, passed the bbl binary path to the --kernel option of the script. gem5 shows
'Starting Simulation...' and it just hangs without any output. How can I specify a binary that the bbl can execute? Are there any kernels that can be booted on gem5 RISCV FS mode? Can anyone provide some resources on FS mode in gem5 RISCV.

Answer (score 0):

In the current implementation of GEM5, RISC-V only supports Bare Metal applications. So when you pass the flag --kernel, it is actually converted to --boot-loader internally and run as a bare-metal ELF.

You can find out what's going on by enabling the execution flags, will will display a trace of instruction log.

`--debug-flags=Exec`